# How to get around error "Unrecognized field "Name, not marked as ignorable", to insert JSON data into H2 database with Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to insert the following json data into H2 database with Spring by following the process shown in this [Dan Vega video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGdKmF2UzSc&list=LLfV_dVWFmzCxLBNfLxA3nyQ&index=7&t=0s). But, I get the following error:

**Error**:

> Unable to save products: Unrecognized field "Name" (class com.saurabhsomani.domain.Product), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "salesCount", "price", "name", "category", "cust_rating", "id"])
> at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.saurabhsomani.domain.Product["Name"])

Could you please help me fix this issue? Below are the code details:

My **JSON** (product.json) looks like:

```
[{
        "Name": "P1",
        "ID": 1,
        "Price": 970,
        "SalesCount": 300,
        "Category": "A",
        "Cust_Rating": 3.7
    },
    {
        "Name": "P2",
        "ID": 2,
        "Price": 1170,
        "SalesCount": 718,
        "Category": "A",
        "Cust_Rating": 3.8
    },
    {
        "Name": "P3",
        "ID": 3,
        "Price": 1090,
        "SalesCount": 1253,
        "Category": "A",
        "Cust_Rating": 0.5
    }
]
```

Project Structure looks like:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynYvR.png)

**JsondbApplication.java**

```
package com.saurabhsomani;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.saurabhsomani.domain.Product;
import com.saurabhsomani.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JsondbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(JsondbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(ProductService productService){ //will help us when the application starts up
        return args -> { //functional interface
            //read json and write to db
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            //We want a list of products
            TypeReference<List<Product>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Product>>(){};
            InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/product.json");
            try{
                //mapper helps us map json structure to the domain object
                List<Product> products = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
                productService.save(products);
                System.out.println("Products Saved!");
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to save products: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**ProductController.java**

```
package com.saurabhsomani.controller;

import com.saurabhsomani.domain.Product;
import com.saurabhsomani.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {
    //no business logic in controller

    private ProductService productService;

    //constructor
    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    public ProductService getProductService() {
        return productService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<Product> list(){
        return productService.list();
    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.saurabhsomani.domain;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int price;
    private int salesCount;
    private String category;
    private double cust_rating;

    public Product(){

    }
}
```

**ProductService.java**

```
package com.saurabhsomani.service;

import com.saurabhsomani.domain.Product;
import com.saurabhsomani.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProductService {

    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Product> list(){
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    //to save one product
    public Product save(Product product){
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    //to save list of products
    public void save(List<Product> products) {
        productRepository.saveAll(products);
    }

}
```

**ProductRepository**

```
package com.saurabhsomani.repository;

import com.saurabhsomani.domain.Product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository <Product, String>{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Product class you need to add Jackson's `@JsonProperty` annotation on properties relevant to attributes of source JSON as they are not identical (but differently cased)

```
public class Product {

    ...

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Price")
    private int price;

    @JsonProperty("Cust_Rating")
    private double cust_rating;

    // and others
}
```

P.S. try to avoid underscores in names outside of unit tests and stick to Java Code Conventions (https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: Nikolai Shevchenko, thank you for the solution. It worked. Changed my variable names as per java conventions.